# How to dynamically create users and access their collections in Firebase Firestore?

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

While learning about Firebase Firestore, I am trying to create a test application where users can keep something like an online diary.

Basically, everything works. The user can register. After that, he can create records, view them, and so on.

But at the very beginning, I mistakenly created a collection of "Diaries", which stores all entries, regardless of who their author is.

That is, it turns out that all users see all these records. Of course, this is wrong. I want each user to create a collection that will be named after their email address. All records will be kept there.

Please fix my code.

```dart
class DatabaseService {
  final FirebaseFirestore _db = FirebaseFirestore.instance;

  //For Users
    addUserData(UserModel userData) async {
    await _db.collection("Users").doc(userData.uid).set(userData.toMap());
  }

    Future<List<UserModel>> retrieveUserData() async {
    QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> snapshot =
        await _db.collection("Users").get();
    return snapshot.docs
        .map((docSnapshot) => UserModel.fromDocumentSnapshot(docSnapshot))
        .toList();
    }

        Future<String> retrieveUserName(UserModel user) async {
    DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> snapshot =
        await _db.collection("Users").doc(user.uid).get();
    return snapshot.data()!["displayName"];
    }


  //For Diary entries
  addEntryData(EntryModel entryData) async {
  await _db.collection("Diaries").doc(entryData.uid).set(entryData.toMap());
  }

  Future<List<EntryModel>> retrieveEntryData() async {
     QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> snapshot =
     await _db.collection("Diaries").orderBy("date").get();
     return snapshot.docs
         .map((docSnapshot) => EntryModel.fromDocumentSnapshot(docSnapshot))
         .toList();
   }


}
```

The thing is, I have already started experimenting with it. In particular, I did this:

I added it to receive my user's email:

```dart
Future<String> retrieveUserEmail(UserModel user) async {
    DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> snapshot =
    await _db.collection("Users").doc(user.uid).get();
    return snapshot.data()!["email"];
  }
```

And I changed this code for entries:

```dart
Future<void> addEntryData(UserModel user, EntryModel entryData) async {
      final userDiary = retrieveUserEmail(user);
      await _db.collection(userDiary as String).doc(entryData.uid).set(entryData.toMap());
  }

Future<List<EntryModel>> retrieveEntryData(UserModel user) async {
    final userDiary = retrieveUserEmail(user);

    QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> snapshot =
    await _db.collection(userDiary as String).orderBy("date").get();
    return snapshot.docs
        .map((docSnapshot) => EntryModel.fromDocumentSnapshot(docSnapshot))
        .toList();
  }
```

But when I started fixing all the other files in my project, I ran into so many errors that now I am not sure if I made the right changes.

Comment: (not a downvoter) "Please fix my code" is not a great way to ask for help on Stack Overflow. I quickly spotted one problem in your code and gave an answer for that below, but highly recommend reading [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) before continuing. Following the guidance in there will make it more likely that someone here can efficiently help, and makes it much less likely that you'll receive downvotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to say what the many errors are, but once of them is in here:

```
Future<void> addEntryData(UserModel user, EntryModel entryData) async {
  final userDiary = retrieveUserEmail(user);
  await _db.collection(userDiary as String).doc(entryData.uid).set(entryData.toMap());
}
```

Since `retrieveUserEmail` returns a `Future<String>`, your `userDiary` is a `Future<String>` not an actual string yet. You'll want to `await` the result:

```
Future<void> addEntryData(UserModel user, EntryModel entryData) async {
  final userDiary = await retrieveUserEmail(user);
  await _db.collection(userDiary).doc(entryData.uid).set(entryData.toMap());
}
```

There may be more problems, but this is definitely one of them.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, this is one of the errors. And there are others. I have carefully read your answer and comment. I will try to fix my errors. And if I still have questions, I will ask them in the correct form.

Thanks again.